# How can I open an editor from a script in pycharm?

Tags: python, subprocess, pycharm

I'm trying to open an editor in the terminal in pycharm, running the script below and am getting the error:

> Error opening terminal: unknown.

The `EDITOR` env var is set to `/usr/bin/nano`.

The env var is being read correctly in the MVE below.

I can open the editor if I call `$EDITOR` from the pycharm terminal command line directly.

The script works if called from a new terminal window, either inside or outside of pycharm.

The problem only arises when running it from a run configuration.

```
import os
import subprocess


def main():
    editor = os.getenv('EDITOR')
    with open('new.txt', 'w+') as tmp:
        subprocess.call([editor, tmp.name])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've found a few related questions, but nothing that explains what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be to check the `[✓] Emulate terminal in output console` checkbox in the `Run/Debug Configurations` window. This doesn't quite produce a functioning terminal session (there are issues with not seeing keyboard inputs after exiting the editor), but it works just well enough for my debugging purposes.